# why req.logIn () doesn't store data when using angular?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on angular and nodejs and their libraries, passport, passport-local, express, express-session. the req.logIn () does not save the data to the session, I tried the rest api with postman and it works correctly, and it saves the data, what is happening ?. could someone help please thank you in advance?

this is the code that according to passport closes the session:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('logout');
 });
```

add cors handling to be able to communicate with another port and activate the credentials for sending the cookie:

```
app.use(cors({origin:["http://localhost:4200"],credentials:true}));

const store = new session.MemoryStore; *//session configuration*
app.use(session({
    secret:"SECRET",
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true,
    cookie:{
        secure: false
    },
    store:store
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());*//initialize passport and passport sessions*
app.use(passport.session());

the login part is like this:

    exports.Login = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, usuario, info) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
        }
        if (!usuario) {
            res.json(info)
        }
        else {
            req.logIn(usuario, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(err)
                }
                else {
                    res.json("usuario existente"})
                    next()
                }
            })
        }
    })(req,res, next)
}
```

Comment: you need to provide a minimal code example to reproduce this

Comment: @ Rachid O update the question in adding a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tried with Postman and it worked and it means Express is working fine. so you need to check your Angular side.

because you are working with Session you need to set the correct setting:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SessionInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const newRequest = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    return next.handle(newRequest);
  }
}
```

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SessionInterceptor, multi: true } ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

[Angular 6 httpClient Post with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210662/angular-6-httpclient-post-with-credentials)

Comment: Thank you very much :) for the information provided and support